# CircleCI/Sauce Labs proxy works but does not run Grunt task

Tags: gruntjs, circleci, saucelabs

I am trying to integrate with Sauce Labs to run my project's Protractor tests, [using CircleCI's guide as a basis](http://circleci.com/docs/1.0/browser-testing-with-sauce-labs/). The tests are wrapped in a Grunt task, which runs flawlessly on my machine:

```
grunt.registerTask('test:protractor', [
    'ngconstant:dev',
    'modernizr:prod',
    'sass',
    'protractor'
]);
```

This is my circle.yml file:

```
dependencies:
  pre:
    - sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install ruby-sass
    - npm install -g bower
    - bower install
  post:
    - wget https://saucelabs.com/downloads/sc-latest-linux.tar.gz
    - tar -xzf sc-latest-linux.tar.gz

test:
  override:
    - cd sc-*-linux && ./bin/sc --user $SAUCE_USERNAME --api-key $SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY --readyfile ~/sauce_is_ready:
        background: true
    # Wait for tunnel to be ready
    - while [ ! -e ~/sauce_is_ready ]; do sleep 1; done
    - grunt test:protractor
        background: true
  post:
    - killall --wait sc  # wait for Sauce Connect to close the tunnel
```

[The Sauce Connect proxy clearly works according to build output:](https://circleci.com/gh/spamguy/dipl.io/131)

```
30 May 18:18:46 - Started scproxy on port 35557.
30 May 18:18:46 - Please wait for 'you may start your tests' to start your tests.
30 May 18:19:03 - Provisioned tunnel:4b38b707d2174ebf9714f05cd8c06f79
30 May 18:19:03 - Using no proxy for connecting to tunnel VM.
30 May 18:19:03 - Starting Selenium listener...
30 May 18:19:03 - Establishing secure TLS connection to tunnel...
30 May 18:19:03 - Selenium listener started on port 4445.
30 May 18:19:04 - Sauce Connect is up, you may start your tests.
```

But at that point, it totally stalls. No effort to call grunt test:protractor, no activity whatsoever. After 10 minutes I killed the build.

What am I missing from this configuration to run Protractor tests through the Sauce Labs proxy?

Comment: What does your Protractor configuration look like? Have you set your sauce labs information in your config?

Comment: I realize the task 'grunt test:protractor' is actually a group of subtasks, of which Protractor is the last. SASS processing, for example, should have some sort of output, but clearly doesn't. I'm removing Protractor from this question, as it doesn't really apply. The real question, then, is why the Grunt task doesn't run.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to install grunt

```
dependencies:
  pre:
    - npm install -g grunt
```

Comment: A reasonable idea! But the shell command 'grunt' already appears to work, because my existing CircleCI build (without Protractor) already runs 'grunt test' without complaint: https://circleci.com/gh/spamguy/dipl.io/134